# Get address or eos account transactions

Tags: transactions, eosjs, rpc, keosd, deposit

I want to get transaction list of request address or account using EOSJS or any RPC method. Kindly guide for it. As per check EOS dev documentation unable to find method which fullfill this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

> cleos --url https://eos.greymass.com get actions eosio.ram  -1 -20

The above command would give you the last 20 transactions in the account *eosio.ram*

To consume the result in JSON add *--json* flag

> cleos --url https://eos.greymass.com get actions eosio.ram  -1 -20 --json

- For more context regarding `get actions`see EOS Developer Doc here: [Exchange Deposit Withdraw](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/exchange-deposit-withdraw)

Comment: Thank you for help.